# AUFS: How to create a read/write branch of only part of a directory tree?

Tags: linux, boot, mount, aufs, unionfs

AuFS (another union file system) allows us to merge two trees into one, even when those trees overlap.
We can then direct writes to the merged tree towards one of the branches and reads to another.

The classic use of this is with a flash file system and a ram disk, like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash) (ref 1) to create a read-only root file system that does not break Linux.  All file writes go to ram. After a reboot the system restore itself to the as-shipped configuration.

- `/dir1` = read only
- `/dir2` = read/write
- `/aufs` = merge of `/dir1` and `/dir2`

`/aufs` is then re-mounted with `--move` to make it `/` (root)

Simplified, the example in (ref 1) just does this

```
mount -t aufs br=/dir2:/dir1 /aufs
mount --move /aufs /
```

However, I want to use it such that the writable (`/dir2`) is on a real disk, not a ramdisk. That way after a reboot it will retain it's data.

But I need to ensure certain files in dir2 are not preserved and are restored to their (`/dir1`) defaults. This ensures future boots always use the as-shipped files. Without loosing user and logging data.

e.g. Changed files in `/etc`, `/bin`, `/boot`, `/usr` should not survive a reboot.

The [AUFS web page](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs.html) (ref 2) has very few examples.

So to the question: What is the correct way to do this using AuFS?

I can think of the following:

1. Modify the first mount command in some way
2. Add more mount commands using the aufs add/del before second mount
3. Simply delete the trees that should not be preserved from `/dir2` at boot time
4. Partial tree (`etc, bin, boot, lib, etc`) in `tmpfs`

Ref 1: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash
Ref 2: http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1**: `auFS` by itself dosen't support such a mount option, so option #1 is dead. You have to work around that.

**Option #3**: Of course, you can simply delete at each bootup those directories. It may be the simplest way I see here.

**Option #2**: You could work with a `tmpfs`. So first create a `tmpfs`, let's say of size 500 MB:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o rw,size=500M tmpfs /tmpfs
```

We have now:

- `/dir1`: read only
- `/dir2`: read/write
- `/tmpfs`: read/write in RAM
- `/aufs`: the overlay of `/dir1` and `/dir2`

Inside `/tmpfs`, we create those dirs you want to preserve:

```
mkdir -p /tmpfs/{etc,usr,boot,bin}
```

Notice, we do that when we already merge the two dirs. So when the directory tree in `/aufs` already exists. However, now we do one aufs mount per directory that should be preserved:

```
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/tmpfs/etc=rw:/dir2/etc=ro none /aufs/etc
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/tmpfs/usr=rw:/dir2/usr=ro none /aufs/usr
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/tmpfs/boot=rw:/dir2/boot=ro none /aufs/boot
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/tmpfs/bin=rw:/dir2/bin=ro none /aufs/bin
```

You have now a directory tree in `/aufs` wehre you can write files everywhere, but when you write into `/etc` for example, it will be written into `/tmpfs/etc`, which is in RAM, therefore doesn't survive a reboot. Other files in `/home` for example are written to `/dir2/home`, which is a read-writeable filesystem and therefore survives a reboot.

**Another solution**: I also use client system that use an overlay filesystem and preserved user data. Here is how I solved it: Simply a read only filesystem and a tmpfs that is mounted over it. Later when the user logs in I mount his home directory from a samba server read-writable. So all his user data is stored and preserved in `/home`, and the rest doesn't survive a reboot. In your case you could just put `/home` into another physical partition that is read-writable and mount that later to `/aufs/home`.

Comment: Thanks chaos, very helpful.  I can't use remote mounts as this is an isolated system.  Looks like a text file with a list of dirs to remove at boot will be the best option. I'll implement that and report back.  Edited question to include partial tmpfs, though I probably can't use this as there is limited RAM.

Comment: @JasonMorgan It must not be a tmpfs, just a place where you can write.